# How to read a set builder notation describing relations

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

I came across the following question:

*Given are the following relations on the functions from $\{1,...,10\}$ to $\{1,...,10\}$*
**R1 = {(f,g) | f(1)=g(1)}**
*Is this relation reflexive?*

I don't know how to read the part, $f(1)=g(1)$ of this set builder notation. Are $f(1)$ and $g(1)$ referring to the first element of $\{1,...,10\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote $S = \{1,2, \ldots, 10\}$. Consider two functions $f, g: S \to S$, then we can ask if $f(1) = g(1)$ (that is: 'is the image of 1 under $f$ and $g$ the same?). If so, we define these functions $f$ and $g$ to be related and the relation is the set $R_1$. So for all functions $f,g$ such that $f(1) = g(1)$, we have that $(f,g) \in R_1$.

$\textbf{SPOILER:}$
Now this relation is

> reflexive

since we have that

> f(1) = f(1), $\forall f: S \to S$.

Comment: Is this reasoning correct? The function f and g can have all values of {1,....,10} as arguments, and R1 only contains (1,1). Because 1 maps to itself, this relation is reflexive.

Comment: Not really: we consider all functions, but are only interested in the image of 1 under all these possible functions. Consider the following three functions: $f, g, h$ with $f(1) = 3, g(1) = 3, h(1) = 7$, then $(f,g) \in R_1$ (since they map 1 onto the same element) but $(f,h) \notin R_1$ since they map 1 to different elements. Now clearly for all functions $t$ we have that $t$ and $t$ map 1 onto the same element!

Comment: The examples made it clear for me!

Answer (score 1):

They are saying that the pair $(f,g)$ is in the set $R_1$ if and only if $f(1)=g(1)$. The condition for being a pair in $R_1$ is equality for an argument of $1$. Does that make sense?

Can you now tell whether or not the relation is reflexive?